# Finding the total capacity of two communication channels

Tags: information-theory, communication-protocols

I have the transition matrices of two communication channels. I am able to find the capacity of each by performing an optimization calculation, however I need the total capacity of the two channels. The channels are not weakly symmetric so I don't think I am able to simply add the two capacities. I think what I need to do is perform the optimization calculation over the combined channels but I'm not sure how to do this. I think I need to construct a transition probability matrix but I'm not sure how to go about this. If anyone can give some advice on this I'd be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: There seems to be some information missing here. Are the channels coupled? If not, the capacity is additive. See for example Wyner, [Capacity of Product of Channels](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82135124.pdf).

Comment: For general channels, you can use the [Blahut–Arimoto algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blahut%E2%80%93Arimoto_algorithm) to computer the channel capacity.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what do you mean by coupled in this context?

Comment: We can describe the operation of a channel as accepting an input $X$, a random variable $N$, and deterministically outputting $Y = f(X,N)$. In your case, you have $X_1,X_2,N_1,N_2,Y_1,Y_2$, and the question is whether $N_1,N_2$ are independent.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus In that case I believe they are independent so they must be additive, thanks for your comment!

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Please edit the question to clarify the problem.  Apparently we have two individual channels (for which you have transition matrices), and they are somehow combined to form a single channel. How, exactly?  Mathematics to specify the problem setting might help.  It would help to specify the random process by specifying the random process (the random variables and how they are related).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the channels are not coupled (i.e., their effect on the input is independent of each other) then their combined capacity is the sum of their individual capacities. See for example Wyner, [Capacity of Product of Channels](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82135124.pdf), who also considers the converse.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider different scenarios. 
The capacity of a broadcast channel is different than a multiple access channel. The total capacity also varies for symmetric and asymmetric channels. See "Network Information Theory" by Abbas El Gamal and Young-Han Kim

Comment: I'm looking for a general method for not necessarily symmetric channels. I'm trying to construct a transition matrix for the total channel, which I believe would be a broadcast channel. For a simple case, consider two erasure channels. I want to find the total capacity of the two in parallel by constructing a transition matrix and optimizing.

Comment: Please see chapter 9 of Network Information Theory by Abbas El Gamal and Young-Han Kim on Vector Channels.